# How to configure gdb to load symbols?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, debian, debug-symbols

I'm trying to run the exim4 mail server that ships with Debian 7.7.0 in gdb with debug symbols.  I've installed the debug symbols using apt-get install exim4-dbg which seem to be located in /usr/lib/debug.  When I try to attach to the exim process I get the following: (no debug symbols found)

```
Attaching to process 25318
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/exim4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdb-5.1.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libthread_db.so.1".
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnss_compat.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnss_nis.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnss_dns.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_mdns4.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
0xb765c424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) show debug-file-directory
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug".
(gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right thing. You just need to `apt-get install exim4-daemon-light-dbg` or `exim4-daemon-heavy-dbg`. Then gdb should find the symbols the way you are currently running it.